# How to fix the dead code error after placing multiproviders?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, dart-pub

error message:

> Try removing the code, or fixing the code before it so that it can be
> reached.

How can I fix this? I tried everything else I couldn't.

> I need the MaterialApp to appear because it is part of the application
> and I cannot remove this part of the code because it is the main
> screen of the application.

error image;

> [Dead Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22nzy.png)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import './views/products_overview_screen.dart';
import './utils/app_routes.dart';
import './views/product_detail_screen.dart';
import './providers/products.dart';
import './providers/cart.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        Provider<Products>(create: (_) => Products()),
      ],
      builder: (context, child) {
        final cart = context.watch<Cart>();
        return Text('$cart');
      },
    );
    MaterialApp(
      title: 'Minha Loja',
      theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.purple,
          accentColor: Colors.deepOrange,
          fontFamily: 'Lato'),
      home: ProductsOverviewSceen(),
      routes: {
        AppRoutes.PRODUCT_DETAIL: (ctx) => ProductDetailsScreen(),
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change it to this:

```
return Text('$cart');
      },
    
child:   MaterialApp
.
.
.
.
) // Add the parenthesis at the end.
```

Comment: What was happening is that t the extra parenthesis `) ` before material widget was telling flutter that everything is done. But we're not done yet, we tell it that there's a child.